# Nodejs and socket.io to send json changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I've successfully used nodejs and socket.io to send a large json file from a server to a client, but I'm stumped on the next step:  I need to analyse the json, and only send changes to the client, so that I have very fast real-time updates on the client-side, without having to send the entire json every second.  I fear I'm missing something really basic.  It's currently sending the entire json over and over.  I see where that's happening, I just don't see how to send, instead, only the CHANGES.  Ideas?

**Server**:

```
/***************************  Require modules  ********************************/
var app = require('express')()
  , request = require('request')
  , fs = require('fs')
  , http = require('http')
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

/*************************  Start socket server  ******************************/

server.listen(8127);

// socket.io 
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){ 

var options = {
    host: 'host.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/api/tomyjson.json',
    headers: {
     'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer('username' + ':' + 'password').toString('base64')
   }         
};


function getStreams() {
    http.get(options, function(response){
        var data = "";
        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function() {
         socket.emit('news', JSON.parse(data));
        });

    });
}

  setInterval(getStreams, 5000);

  socket.on('message', function(data){
        console.log(data)
}) 
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){

}) 

});
```

**Client JS**:

```
var socket = io.connect('host.com:8127/');
    socket.on('news', function (json) {
           $.each(json.data, function(i, x) {
            console.log(x.json.element);
            $('#stream-container').prepend(x.json.element);

            })
        socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
      });

    socket.on('message', function(data){
        // Do some stuff when you get a message
        oldData += data;
        document.getElementById('stream-container').innerHTML = oldData;
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        // Do some stuff when disconnected
    });
```

Comment: Do you have control over how the JSON file gets updated?

Comment: No, I can just read it.  But I KNOW how it gets updated, which is to say, new (changed) rows (the ones I need) are added at the start of the file.

Comment: You could count the number of rows and only emit new rows coming in. So keep the initial count then after every get, see if the row count has changed.